# ArgoCD with Terraform to delete all applications when deleting the namespace argocd

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm, argocd

I am installing `argocd` into my Kubernetes clusters with helm in Terraform like so:

```hashicorp
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "ns_argocd" {
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      name = "argocd"
    }
    name = "argocd"
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "argocd" {
  name = "argocd"
  repository = "https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm"
  chart      = "argo-cd"
  version    = "3.27.1"

  create_namespace = false
  namespace        = kubernetes_namespace.ns_argocd.0.metadata.0.name

  depends_on = [kubernetes_namespace.ns_argocd]
}
```

It works really nice, I can create applications, deploy resources and so on. But if I try to run a `terraform destroy`, the deletion of the namespace `argocd` gets stuck with status `terminating`. This is because the applications defined in the argocd namespace are not correctly removed and I had to do some workarounds to delete it manually, mainly removing the finalizers from the definition.

Is there a way that running the `destroy` command will remove the applications defined in the `argocd` namespace when deleting the namespace?

Comment: I see that you are already using `depends_on`, I've seen some stubborn cases where I  tested manually setting those and no luck resources will not destroy as intended ... my only option was to create a `null_resource` that will do the removal of the of those pieces that need to go

Comment: This is actually an issue with the Argo Helm chart release deletion, and should probably be approached from that direction and not the Terraform config.

Comment: Could you share an example of how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue and the only way I found to solve it was explicitly destroying the applications before destroying ArgoCD itself. I created a bash script with something like below:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

# remove apps deployed by argocd
terraform destroy -auto-approve -target kubectl_manifest.apps_dev
terraform destroy -auto-approve -target kubectl_manifest.apps_staging
terraform destroy -auto-approve -target kubectl_manifest.apps_prod
terraform destroy -auto-approve -target kubernetes_namespace.complex_app

# remove argocd itself
terraform destroy -auto-approve -target kubernetes_namespace.argocd

# destroy everything else
terraform destroy -auto-approve
```

N.B. I know it isn't how Terraform is supposed to be used.